# Facebook SDK 4.0 IOS Swift Log a user out programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode-6.2

In some cases in my application i need to log the user out, but i only have the FBSDKLoginButton instance in my view controller and implementing the

```
FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
```

using

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
```

I want to pop the login view after logging the user out (destroying Facebook session)
Don't know how to use

```
FBSDKLoginManager.logOut(<#FBSDKLoginManager#>)
```

I'am working inside a UIViewController and referencing the FBSDKLoginButton through an outlet

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Ok, here is the thing for anyone needs assistance.
I managed to log my users out using **FBSDKLoginManager** instance

Apparently and i don't know if is it documented or not **FBSDKLoginManager** watches

```
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

so

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logOut() // this is an instance function
```

Logs the user out, what i misunderstood that **logOut** is not a class function.

Comment: I am calling this from a tabbar controller and returning to my rootview controller i.e. my login in controller. When I return to this login view controller, I am seeing the log "user logged out", so the logout worked but I am getting into the function login didCompleteWithResult. Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure you are not calling the login functionality in viewDidAppear inside the loginViewController of yours, this didCompeleteWithResult block should be called only when login action is triggered!
If that didn't help paste the code here

Comment: I don't have any code in a viewdidappear for that controller. Can we move to chat?

Comment: it's fine if you want to chat, create the room please.

Comment: will add `import FBSDKLoginKit`.. to 4.2 Version

Comment: Thanks guys! FB really needs to update their Swift documentation, it contains like 5% of the documentation needed...

Answer (score 35):

**Swifty** and simple answer for lazy ones like me:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

Comment: The problem is that if you call this, once the user tries to log in again with Facebook it'll just say "You have already authorized {App Name}". How can the user log out of Facebook then switch accounts?

Comment: @MarksCode.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368510/how-to-logout-user-using-facebook-authentication-using-swift-and-ios

Comment: Now its: LoginManager().logOut()

Answer (score 18):

For Swift 3 , Facebook SDK 4.16.0: Using [Facebook Swift SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift)

```
LoginManager().logOut()
```

Answer (score 11):

Does the same, but in Objective-C:

`[[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init] logOut];`

Do not forget imports: `FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h` & `FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h`

Comment: It's a bit ugly, isn't it?

Comment: You can add a temporary variable for holding LoginManager for later on calling logOut. But this is the shortest way if I just want to logout. In my opinion LoginManager should have to be implemented as a singleton class  (because at the end is working in that way) and then call [[FBSDKLoginManager shared instance] logOut].

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have used **Parse** and the **Facebook iOS SDK version >= 4.4.0** to sign up or log in a user via **Facebook**, please use instead:

```
PFUser.logOut()
```

It will log out the user, delete the session on the **Parse** back-end side (do not forget to [enable](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/) Parse [revocable session](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#sessions-handling-invalid-session-token-error) via your Parse app settings), plus it will also delete the **Facebook** session written on the user device's disk.

I hope this answer will help you guys.