# Confirm Screen blank after clicking login to facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developing an app that uses `facebook login`. Everything was working fine for a long time until I uninstalled the app from the phone manually and installed it again.

Now whenever I click the login button It redirects me to the `facebook page` where the message `Confirm` next to the `facebook logo`. Alas there is nothing I can click on and the rest of the page is blank.

What is going on (I logged in to this app before from this phone and I had no problems)

Here is my login code: (let me know if anything else will help)

```
 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    print("User Logged In")


    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {

        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
            self.view.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
            loadPageContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for logout please use code in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36369118/1142743

Comment: thanks i fixed it for now by logging out. I wonder what is causing this bug and how to avoid it in the future

Comment: Post what you done a answer it will be helpful for others . One of the feature of facebook is to remember the logged in user