# User unable to sign out in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have an iOS device that is either used by many people, or where several different people use Safari on iOS to login to Facebook mobile.

In my case, the previous FB user is already signed in. User 2 wants to connect to Facebook. Right now the UX is

> You have already authorized app XXXXXX

[image]

**Q:** 
What can I do to either logout a user, or ensure that they get to choose which facebook identity they want to use?

Comment: have you tried FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to logout user using Facebook authentication using Swift and iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368510/how-to-logout-user-using-facebook-authentication-using-swift-and-ios)