# Google/Facebook sign-out isn't persistent

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, google-signin

I am writing an iOS app and have implemented both Google and Facebook sign in methods.

When I log out of the app, I am taken to my log in screen.

If I close the app and open it again, I am already logged back in.

I want it to take me to my log in screen, and for some reason it remembers my as logged in. Maybe I need to clean some sort of cache?

My logout function after clicking a button:

```
@IBAction func LogOutButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        // MARK - should Prompt user if to log out
        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser != nil)
        {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        }

        else if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
        {
            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut()
        }
        // Unwind segue to login screen

        isLoggingOut = true
    }
```

I looked for an answer but couldn't find any similar to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically logout the user as mentioned below.

For **Facebook** you can logout through below line:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

Remember the **access token** should be valid for the session.

```
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

For **Google** signout you can try out:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

If its properly sign out you will be redirected login screen.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing

Comment: I added my logout function

Comment: This would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368510/how-to-logout-user-using-facebook-authentication-using-swift-and-ios

Comment: @Ofri here set your local flag value first then call logout from FB or GP methods hope this work for you

Comment: @KetanSodvadiya Are you talking about the thread Rahul added ?